# CiviCRM on Drupal: Array to string conversion error in BAO setting.php in Display preferences

Tags: installation, configuration, civicrm, debugging

I'm receiving this error after a fresh install of [civicrm-4.4.17](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm) on
drupal-7.38.

[image: array to string conversion in BAO setting]

While attempting to go through the configuration checklist I also noticed that the items were not turning green after I completed them.

[image: civicrm site configuration staying red]

What might be causing these errors?